# Arbitrary Assignment in Method

Tags: c#, entity-framework

I was looking through the internals of [DbSet](https://github.com/aspnet/EntityFrameworkCore/blob/dev/src/EFCore/Internal/InternalDbSet.cs) when I came across some wierd code:

```
private void CheckState()
{
    // ReSharper disable once AssignmentIsFullyDiscarded
    _ = EntityType;
}
```

Note _ is not declare anywhere they are using the new C# 7.0 Discard operator.  Why would someone want to do something like this?  Is there any benefit of doing this?

**Edit**

```
private IEntityType EntityType
    {
        get
        {
            _context.CheckDisposed();

            if (_entityType != null)
            {
                return _entityType;
            }

            _entityType = _context.Model.FindEntityType(typeof(TEntity));

            if (_entityType == null)
            {
                throw new InvalidOperationException(CoreStrings.InvalidSetType(typeof(TEntity).ShortDisplayName()));
            }

            return _entityType;
        }
    }
```

Comment: To suppress ReSharper warnings, I suppose. If it just calls the method like that ReSharper will remind you that there is an unused return value.

Comment: Impossible to say without seeing the rest of the code. But, if `EntityType` is a property, it's possible the getter has some side-effect the code author desires (not a good characteristic for a property getter, but that's how things are sometimes). (Since it turns out your link goes straight to the module where the property is defined, I can see that indeed that property caches a value, and so it's possible the author wants to force the value to be retrieved and/or validated to exist.) All we can offer though are opinions; only the author of that code can tell you for sure why they did it.

Comment: There is a link to the code in the question on GitHub

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That looks like a property `get` access that has a side-effect. You can't invoke a property without either assigning it to something (or passing it as an expression) (for the `get`), or assigning something to it (for the `set`). They can't just have:

```
EntityType;
```

All they're doing is making it clear that they want to discard the result of the `get`, presumably to avoid an unused variable warning.

Comment: it sounds like a side effect, I’ve made an edit to the question to include the property.  Doesn’t make much sense still, I don’t see anything to obvious

Comment: @johnny5 it runs a lot of "are thing correct and happy" logic - they're just trying to invoke that; in particular the disposed check, but also the config check (which is only done once, via the stored field short-circuiting that check)

Comment: That makes sense, I feel like a validate method would of made things more clear but then again that source is intended to be hidden normally.  Thanks for your expertise